# преобразование из unit в library

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7

У меня есть такой код:

```
unit No_NULL;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}


interface


uses ComObj, ActiveX, StdVcl, S4_TLB, sbserver_TLB,Windows, Variants;

const
  Class_Splugin: TGUID = '{6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF}';

type
   Splugin = class(TAutoObject, ISearchPlugin, ISearchPluginArticles, ISearchPluginSP, ISearchPluginDocument)
    public
      protected
    function ErrorMessage(ErrorCode: Integer): WideString; safecall;
    ...

implementation


uses ComServ, Dialogs, SysUtils, Controls;

function Splugin.ErrorMessage(ErrorCode: Integer): WideString;
begin

end;

...

initialization


  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, Splugin, Class_Splugin,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

Отрабатывает отлично, но мне нужна на выходе библиотека. Когда меняю unit на library, начинает придираться к каждой строчке. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать новый проект типа dll library. К нему подключить ваш модуль и в dpr-файле написать следующее

```
library No_NULLLib;

uses
  ComServ,
  // Подключаем наш модуль
  No_NULL in 'No_NULL.pas';

exports
  // Экспортируем функции для работы с COM
  DllGetClassObject,
  DllCanUnloadNow,
  DllRegisterServer,
  DllUnregisterServer;

{$R *.RES}
{$R S4.tlb}  // Добавляем tlb себе в ресурсы

end.
```